# How do I trap new row adds in a list?

Tags: excel, list, events

I want to execute an VBA event handler in an Excel 10 worksheet whenever the user adds a new row into a list (the kind of lists that `Worksheet.ListObjects`() returns instances of) on that worksheet, for example by entering data under the last row of the list (this expands the list by adding a new row to the list).

**How do I do that?** Among other things, I want to set defaults for specific cells of the new row.

My current idea is to handle `Worksheet_Change`, and check if the `Target` parameter is within the `.Range` of the `ListObject` I am interested in.

However, how would I find out if the user is creating a new row with his/her cell change, and differentiate that from edits of existing cells in the list?

I probably am just a little bit stupid here. I´d expect there would be a list event I could trap, but I cannot find any.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are right, there are no Events for `ListObject`'s.  Using `Worksheet_Change` seems the right way to go.  To detect New Row vs Existing Row edit you will need to roll you own method.

I would suggest tracking the number of rows in the `ListOjects` in order to detect when they change.  In order to do this, try adding a hidden `named range` for each `ListOject` to hold the current number of rows. Populate them on file open, and test them on `Worksheet_Change`.

This will add or update hidden named ranges on file open (add to Workbook module)

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Dim oList As ListObject
    Dim sh As Worksheet
    Dim nm As Name
    Dim strName As String

    For Each sh In Me.Worksheets
    For Each oList In sh.ListObjects
        'oList.ListRows.Count
        strName = oList.Name & "Rows"
        Set nm = Nothing
        On Error Resume Next
        Set nm = Me.Names(strName)
        On Error GoTo 0
        If nm Is Nothing Then
            Set nm = Me.Names.Add(strName, CStr(oList.ListRows.Count))
        Else
            nm.RefersTo = CStr(oList.ListRows.Count)
        End If
        nm.Visible = False
    Next oList, sh
End Sub
```

This will detect what type of change was made. I've made it a WorkBook level event, so only one is needed for all sheets. (add to Workbook module)

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim oList As ListObject
    Dim nm As Name
    Dim strName As String

    For Each oList In sh.ListObjects
        strName = oList.Name & "Rows"
        If Not Application.Intersect(Target, oList.DataBodyRange) Is Nothing Then
            Set nm = Nothing
            On Error Resume Next
            Set nm = Me.Names(strName)
            On Error GoTo 0
            If nm Is Nothing Then
                Set nm = Me.Names.Add(strName, CStr(oList.ListRows.Count))
                nm.Visible = False
            End If
            If oList.ListRows.Count <> Val(Replace(nm.Value, "=", "")) Then
                nm.RefersTo = CStr(oList.ListRows.Count)
                MsgBox "List " & oList.Name & " changed" & vbCrLf & "New Line"
            Else
                MsgBox "List " & oList.Name & " changed" & vbCrLf & "Existing Line"
            End If
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Note: this does not handle the case where the name of an existing ListObject is changed.  This is left as an exercise for the reader

Comment: Too bad there seems to be no better. more compact way. But hey thanks.